# Meteor client side javascript minification and mearging but no mangling variable names

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, How to minify and merge javascript on the client side; but don't mangle/change variable names/function names?

Is there any bundling option available?

EDIT:
I am currently using : `meteor bundle` with `--debug` options; but is not doing any minification at all. I am looking to bundle as well as merge all js and cs files.

On changing the variable names my js scripts breaks !
What is the command which meteor uses while bundling the client side js ..is it with uglify.. what are the options i can simply remove the "mangling variable names option"

NOTE:
i don't want to use meteor --production or meteor bundle --debug. Since they keep all the files .. i have hell lot of files. And the js files from the packages. I simply don't want this for performance reasons.

Answer (score 7):

Meteor automatically minifies and bundles your CSS and JS on the client when you run it in production mode:

```
meteor --production
```

Comment: meteor bundle with --debug options; but is not doing any minification at all. I am looking to bundle as well as mearge all js and cs files.

Comment: @naveen That's the intended functionality. `meteor bundle` minifies and bundles all files by default. If you use `meteor bundle --debug` it will not minify. You can see this by running `meteor help bundle`. The purpose of the `debug` option is to allow you to see the line numbers where errors or unexpected functionality are occurring, as well as to better use your browser's debugging functionality. If you minify your files, you can't do that

Comment: I want just to minify, but not to changing the variable names since my js is dependent on variable names

Comment: Meteor should not change any external variable names when minifying... It should work just fine. What names are changing?

Comment: It does change all the variable names.. :(

Comment: What is the command which meteor uses while bundling the client side js ..is it with uglify.. what are the options i can simply remove the "mangling variable names option"

Comment: @naveen can you post your source code? Your global variable names (those that you define without `var`) should not be changed. For example, if you go to http://meteor.com they are running Meteor in production mode with minified JS/CSS, but global variables like `Meteor`, `Template`, `EJSON`, etc are available in the console. I think you might be expecting file-local variables to be available globally, but Meteor wraps all your files in IIFEs so you need to define your globals without `var`.

Comment: Sir, i never talked abt global,, i am using a library where internal names do matter,, i just wanted to .. to minify and mearge javascripts on the client side; but don't mangle/change variable names/function names

Comment: I understand but if you would post some code your problem would be much easier to solve. Meteor's minifier should not be breaking your code.

Comment: Unfortunately .. where i work i can't share code. .But you ca try it ; all local variable names are getting renamed. so now if you don't minify there are 100's of js files .. How to minify and mearge javascripts on the client side; js of clientside files and js of client side in packages folder ; but don't mangle/change variable names/function names?