# how to hide the js files in the header in meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

This is my first time develop an app using meteor, I find out there are many js files included in , like files from the default/installed packages and the clients files.

However when I view the  in the live sites that created by meteor, there are very little or no js files in there at all. How can do this?

I can't find the information about this topic. Is it because the meteor will hide these js files once the app is deployed?

Comment: I have never worked with meteor, but I'm sure it's due to some sort of minification/bundling step.  Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21129335/691711).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when your application will be deployed you'll not see them anymore. Like said by zero298, they will be minified and bundled.

Comment: Yes, you are right. With --production, i can see the files has been minified. Thanks